# Acessar variavel em outra função, javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ola, estou desenvolvendo um Bot de discord e estou tentando fazer um comando que precisa acessar uma variavel criada em outra função.

```
if(msg.content.startsWith('z!setarcanaldenunciasrecebidas')){
    msg.delete();
    var denunciasRecebidas = msg.content.replace('z!setarcanaldenunciasrecebidas','')
    const Embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#ff0000')
    .setDescription('*Canal de denúncias recebidas setado com sucesso!*')
    .setTitle(`**Canal Setado ${msg.author.username}! **`)
    if(denunciasRecebidas < 1){
    msg.channel.send('Você precisa mandar o ID do canal de denuncias recebidas!')
}else{
msg.reply(Embed2)
}

}
if(msg.content.startsWith('z!denunciar')){
  msg.delete();
  let denuncia = msg.content.replace('z!denunciar','')
  let canalDenuncia = msg.gild.channels.cache.find(ch => cd.id === denunciasRecebidas)
const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#ff0000')
.setTitle('Denuncia feita!')
.setDescription('`Sua denuncia foi enviada aos moderadores e administradores do servidor!`')
.setThumbnail('https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/S8KRhIAgTc9g6pXD2VzfnpOrd2243PA_Tv1M6wLhF30/https/images.emojiterra.com/mozilla/512px/274c.png?width=441&height=441')
const Embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#ff0000')
.setDescription('' +denuncia)
.setTitle('Conteúdo da Denuncia:')
.setFooter('✅- Usuário punido | - Em averiguação | ❌- Usuário Não Punido')
.setAuthor (`Autor da denuncia: ${msg.author.username}`)

if(denuncia < 1){
  msg.channel.send('Você precisa escrever o autor e o motivo da denuncia após o comando!')
 }
 else {

     msg.reply(Embed)
     canalDenuncia.send(Embed1).then(messageReaction => {
messageReaction.react('✅')
messageReaction.react(':')
messageReaction.react('❌')
     })
   }
}
```

Preciso acessar a variavel denunciasRecebidas no outro if de denunciar, mas não é uma variavel global como faço?

Answer (score 0):

Uma variável global que tem escopo global : todos os scripts e funções em uma página da web podem acessá-la. E também mesmo estando dentro ou fora da função, aonde você preferir colocar, você atribui um valor a variável dados mas não a declara (declarações: var let const) ficando apenas denunciasRecebidas = '' (independente de onde esteja)

Se você atribuir um valor a uma variável que não foi declarada, ela se tornará automaticamente uma variável GLOBAL e assim todos os scripts e funções em uma página da web podem acessá-la .

***LEMBRANDO CUIDADO AO FAZER ISSO POIS NENHUMA OUTRA VARIÁVEL PODE OBTER O NOME DE UMA VARIÁVEL GLOBAL, NO CASO QUE FALEI AÍ A VARIÁVEL dados E ALGUNS EXEMPLOS DO SEU CASO SÃO AS VARIÁVEIS linhas e btnVisualizar e tabela QUE VOCÊ DENOMINOU FORA DE FUNÇÕES.***

Em vez de:

```js
    var denunciasRecebidas = msg.content.replace('z!setarcanaldenunciasrecebidas','')
```

Coloque

```js
    denunciasRecebidas = msg.content.replace('z!setarcanaldenunciasrecebidas','')
```